# Excel: Populate Sheet1 with info from Sheet2 if cells match?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

Having trouble finding the proper formula in order to get what I need:
I have a spreadsheet of 1500+ devices with info and a spreadsheet of 1300 or so of those devices with info on whether the devices are bitlockered or not.
If the name (Sheet1 Column A) matches either the device name or friendly name (Sheet2 Column A or Sheet2 Column B) then I want to paste the corresponding cell from the Has Bitlocker column (Sheet2 column D).

Any ideas on how I would be able to accomplish this?

Comment: nest two vlookups in an IFERROR

Comment: Check outindex() and match(), search on here as there are several q&a with them.